# Finding records in mongodb with geolocation (near-feature), did't work if the location field is nested in an object

Tags: mongodb

I try to use geolocation search in mongodb. In a simple case this works fine, as you can see in example 1. But my locations are nested in an address object and I didn't figure out how to do the location search in the second example.

```
# Example 1 - works
db.test1.insert({
    "name" : "location1", 
    "position" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 49.42949, 11.085466 ]}
});

db.test1.createIndex( { position: "2dsphere" } )
db.test1.find({
    position: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [49.475180,10.984163]}, $maxDistance: 15000}}
});

# Example 2 - didn't find records
db.test2.insert({ 
    "name" : "location1", 
    "address": {
        "position" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 49.42949, 11.085466 ]}
    }
});
db.test2.createIndex( { position: "2dsphere" } )

db.test2.find({
    position: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [49.475180,10.984163]}, $maxDistance: 15000}}
});

db.test2.find({
    address: {position: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [49.475180,10.984163]}, $maxDistance: 15000}}}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quote when ever you need to access nested objects

```
db.test2.find({
    'address.position': {
         $near: {
              $geometry: {
                  type: "Point",
                  coordinates: [49.475180,10.984163]
              }, $maxDistance: 15000
         }
     }
});
```